# Post message to wall, without the domain showing up

Tags: facebook, dns, facebook-wall

I have an application hosted on: "foo.com", I post a message on the user wall, and then (obviously) it shows the *site domain* from where the app posted.
My client from hell ("bar.com") doesn't want the "foo.com" domain to be show in the wall post, like this:

[image]

My client has seen that when foursquare (mobile app) post to a users wall, the domain (foursquare.com) doesn't show up on the wall post, like this:

[image]

And he wants that because: "it has to be possible" (he kinda has a point, in his own evil way).

Is there any way to acomplish this? (**he doesn't want to buy a secure domain/hosting**)

I'm using this code:

```
 $arguments = array(  
   'message' => 'my message',  
   'link' => FACEBOOK_PAGE_TAB_URL,  
   'description' => 'The description',  
   'picture' => FACEBOOK_LOGO  
 );

 $this->facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $arguments);
```

Comment: How are you creating your link? Are you using the API to create a link, or are you creating a post? Can you post the specific code involved?

Comment: I'm posting using de PHP SDK, I'll paste the code right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the [feed API endpoint](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed), you are creating a [Post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) with the API. Since your Post contains a link, Facebook is displaying the domain for that hyperlink. As far as I can tell, there is no way to programmatically create a Post with a hyperlink and not have it display a domain.

If it is important that `foo.com` not be shown, you could either make sure that the hyperlink is from `bar.com`, or use the [Feed Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) to allow the user to post the story to their own wall.

I suspect that the reason that the screenshot of the Foursquare post does not display a domain is because they are using the mobile version of the Feed Dialog, as suggested [in Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#socialchannels).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just wanted to check another source for this one.

Answer (score 1):

In the $arguments array... add another field for "caption".  That will replace your domain name :-)

array(
    'message' => 'my message',
    'link' => FACEBOOK_PAGE_TAB_URL,
    'description' => 'The description',
    'picture' => FACEBOOK_LOGO,
    'caption' => "something.com"
);